# Were Remans truly such great bodyguards and soldiers, given their light-sensitivity?

Tags: star-trek, romulan

While reading [Reman](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Reman) definition at Memory Alpha, I found this piece of text:

> As Remus was a tidally locked planet, the Remans live on its dark side, and thus were extremely sensitive to light.

Followed by this one:

> Among the Romulan people, Remans have historically been known as great warriors. As such, Romulan senators often had Reman bodyguards in their employ to intimidate possible opponents.

How can these two texts stands together? How can someone become a great warrior and a good bodyguard, if he / she is "*extremely sensitive to light*"? Romulus is not a tidally locked planet, it has days and nights. How can Remans serve so well in these conditions (mostly, during day)?

Comment: they work the night shift? :)

Comment: LOL! Truly, that could be the answer, but how to imagine a "great bodyguard" if it can secure you only, when you sleep.

Comment: They wear sunscreen?

Comment: Sunshades, goggles, helmets, full body armour, only work inside Buildings etc ,etc.

Comment: As for me, personally, still nothing. I agree with all of you (even those joking), but is it a truly "great" warrior, if it have to keep all these things to work normally. And will it be so successfull, if may fail only because one of these elements were removed by an opponent. Maybe I'm generalizing too much, but I can't imagine a "great" warrior, who isn't able to fight / work / serve in all "normal" conditions (normal to the one, who hires him)?

Comment: Light sensitivity is easily overcome via technology.  As Cherubel says, goggles.  Such things are doable with today's tech.  That would not in any way interfere with their abilities as warriors.

Comment: While, I'm not entirely convinced, this could be an answer to my question. I asume, that there is no in-universe proof of this or any other explanation for the possible contradiction, that I've found. I.e. these are all free speculations, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mentioned in ["Star Trek: The Original Series: Vulcan's Soul #3: Epiphany"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X_HtfwUL6ZQC&dq=T%27Vysse%20star%20trek)

> The guards fell in behind them. Once inside the ship, their suits'
>   visors darkened in what was, to them, the painfully bright light of
>   the ships interior.

So when wearing there suits they use a visor to defend their eyes but they can see in a well-lit environment but feeling a lot of pain.

> He watched as his crew rifled through Karatek's and T'Vysse's packs. 
>   They contained little but the light hooded cloaks they would use on
>   the other world. --- They raised the hood to cover their faces in case
>   lights rose unexpectedly.

This indicates also they use hoods to help dim the light when in unfamiliar enviroments.

As you say, there is a contradiction but they do use other means to still be the great bodyguards.